# SQLite is saving the wrong integer?

Tags: php, sqlite, integer

I have a small PHP webform to store items and prices in a SQLite database.

I store prices in integers, after PHP increases its value *100 (so I indirectly have a rounded to the 2nd decimal price) this way:

```
$form_Price = intval($form_Price*100);
$query = "insert into items values ($form_Name,$form_Price)";
$results = $db->querySingle($query);
```

It usually works fine, no issues until today... I got an item with a $2.28 price tag. When I store it using the PHP form, the field show the value = "227" instead of "228". I tried myself different times, I thought there was a rounding mistake somewhere, but it seems I cannot find this bug.

If I insert manually the value into the database as "228" integer, the form using this code

```
$select_Price = intval($select_Price)/100;
print "Price: $select_price";
```

shows the correct price "2.28". So I think the problem is somewhere between the PHP form saving the price and the sqlite dabase accepting the query.

*I know I should validate and sanitize the forms and the SQL query, but this "thing" is only used by myself as an excercise and it's unreacheable from the internet.*

**EDIT:** As noted by @IncredibleHat replacing intval() with round() actually fixes my problem.

Comment: Sounds like float error. Where `$form_Price*100` is actually equalling `227.9999999999999999999`... then when you do an intval it lops off the end after the decimal. I generally do `number_format($price,2)*100` to store values in pennies.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Ah ha, that makes sense. I still wouldn't store the values in the DB like that though.

Comment: @user3783243 I have mixed feelings about it. I've stored prices as decimal and double, and always visually see some odd float errors... so then I've stored them as pennyInts ... and it avoids it. However, it adds a layer of conversion to and from to store as pennies and return it back. So, mixed bag of hell either way ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat replacing `intval()` with `round()` actually fixes my problem. It's still unclear to me why it only happens seldom and why there's a float error within `intval` but I can live with that, thank you very much!